# SQL Join through Mappings Table

Tags: sql

I may have made the datascheme more complicated than i need to however this is the current data scheem and what im trying got accomplish.

```
Actor
id|name  |website       |...
1 |james |www.james.com |...
2 |ben   |www.ben.com   |...

Movie
id|name      |poster|runtime...
1 |titanic   |/a.jpg|98|
2 |Terminator|/b.jpg|77|
3 |MIB       |/c.jpg|89|

Character
id|name
1 |tony
2 |bilbo
3 |gandalf

ActorMovieCharacterMapping
id|movie_id|actor_id|character_id
1 | 3      |5       |3
2 | 2      |5       |2
3 | 3      |2       |6
```

My goal is to get all of the Actors with their character name for a given movie in the fewest number of SQL queries as possible. I can get all of the actors in a movie or characters in a movie but dont know how to also retrieve that actors character name for that movie. Any help would be appreciated as well as possible ways to format these tables better.

Comment: You only need one query.  It will have multiple `join`s.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle

Answer (score 2):

Just do joins on mapping table:

```
select a.name as actor_name, c.name as character_nane
from ActorMovieCharacterMapping m
join Actor a on m.actor_id = a.id
join Movie mo on m.monie_id = mo.id
join Character c on m.character_id = c.id
where mo.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, sql has always been my weekest point. Needa get more comfortable with it.